# Prove this is a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inner-products, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I'm dealing with an exercise on bilinear forms, but I don't know how to properly start. I have to prove that $\beta(A, B) = \mathrm{tr}(AB) - \mathrm{tr}(A)\mathrm{tr}(B)$ is a bilinear form, where $A, B$ are matrices and we are on the space $V = M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, choosing two general matrices, I computed that
$$\beta(A, B) = a_{12}b_{21} + a_{21}b_{12} - a_{11}b_{22} - a_{22}b_{11}$$

but I don't know if this was necessary.

According to the theory, a function $\phi: V\times V \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bilinear form on $V$ if it is linear in each variable separately.

I also computed the quadratic form $q: M_2(\mathbb{R}) \times M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$, associated to that scalar product (id est, the bilinear form), which should be:

$$q(A, B) = 2a_{12}a_{21} - 2a_{11}a_{22}$$

Is that right?

Anyway to come back to the bilinear (symmetric) form, it's blurred to me how to start the proof. I know how to deal when I have two vectors like $\phi(v, w)$ but here I have two matrices. Or anyway, using the definition I calculated

$$\beta(A, B) = a_{12}b_{21} + a_{21}b_{12} - a_{11}b_{22} - a_{22}b_{11}$$

how should I proceed? It would be something like

$$\beta\Big((a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{21}, a_{22}), (b_{12}, b_{21}, b_{11}, b_{22})\Big)$$

and then I proceed applying the definition of bilinearity?

but this would make... well something like $\beta: \mathbb{R}^4\times \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$....???

Comment: Just use the fact that $tr(cA)=c \, tr(A)$ and $tr(A+B)=tr(A)+tr(B)$,

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you. Didn't really think of that simple thing... Just to say: if I wanted to proceed in the sadistic way, what I wrote is correct? Should I just go on from the last thing I wrote, using the bilinearity definition?

Comment: If people made themselves useful and comment, instead of downvoting, oh! What a wonderful world it would be.

Comment: I would say the moment you computed the formula for $\beta(A,B)$ in line 5 of your post then the proof is over. It is obviously bilinear - if all $a$ are fixed it is a linear function of $b$s and vice versa. Of course the advantage of @geetha290krm 's comment is that it works nicely in any dimension and that it is more "natural" whereas your explicit formula will get longer (although a few summations with $\Sigma$ solve that issue too).

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you so much!! can you please tell me if I wrote some malarkey about the structure of $\beta$? I mean say I really wanted to fo to the end... is $\beta$ such that it's something from $\mathbb{R}^4\times \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$? This might sound useless, but to me it's important. It makes me more confident about those details too...
(And $q$ too)

Comment: How far you need to go sort of depends on what definition of bilinearity you are willing to assume. First you flattened everything to vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, that's fine (strictly speaking, you chose a linear isomorphism of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then you can write $\beta(a,b)=a^T M b$ for some fixed matrix $M$ with four entries, which I'm too tired to type in here but which follows directly from your formula for $\beta$. Does that convince you more?